# compiling java hadoop classes on windows

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to java and hadoop, I am following a tutorial of simple code, but it works on linux, when I tried to compile the java hadoop class I get different errors, after some resolving I am stuck in some errors related to that the packages doesn't exist; I am using hadoop3.2.2, and I try to compile it using this command:

```
javac -classpath "C:/Users/DELL/Downloads/hadoop-3.2.2/bin" stubs/*.java
```

and I already added the hadoop location to the system env variables and I also added all the jar files in eclipse from share/commen and share/mapreduce, and share/yarn for ; here's some of the errors I got:

```
stubs\FileSystemCat.java:10: error: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
                           ^
stubs\FileSystemCat.java:11: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
                           ^
stubs\FileSystemCat.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
                Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                ^
  symbol:   class Configuration
  location: class FileSystemCat
stubs\FileSystemCat.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
                Configuration conf = new Configuration();
  symbol:   variable IOUtils
  location: class FileSystemCat
13 errors
```

Comment: 1) `bin` folder doesn't contain Hadoop classpath libraries. 2) Please use Maven/Gradle instead

Comment: thanks for your comment but what do u mean sorry? should I download something?

Comment: I'm talking about dependency management. Don't use `javac`. Use `maven` or `gradle`. For example, here is a repo of mine for running mapreduce apps https://github.com/OneCricketeer/mapreduce-sandbox/blob/master/build.gradle#L22